# Dynamic Buttons in UIScrollView with Equal width and height

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I want to display list of buttons in scrollview with dynamic height based on screen size. I can able to do this in UIView, but when I applied same auto layout approach in UIScrollView, it's not increasing the size of buttons. So please guide me How to increase the button size in UIScrollView based on screen size.

Comment: We can't help you without knowing what you did. Show us what you did.

Comment: while applying the proportional constraint select main view as the second view and not the scroll view, then u will be able to acheive desired result.

Comment: I have two views V1 and V2.I applied the proportional constraint to V1 and V2.And V2 contain scrollview S1, and S1 contain buttons and textfields with same height.I need to change the S1 elements height based on screen height.And I followed the below link to check how to use the scrollview in view and applied the auto layouts exactly like that.

https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/how-to-configure-a-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder-218dcb4022d7

Answer (score 0):

if button is dynamic and may be increase and decrease in future than you Should use `CollectionView` not `ScrollView`.

1. Drag `CollectionView` into `ViewController`.
2. Drag Cell in `CollectionView`.
3. Add button(or label based on your requirement) In Cell.set button(leading,trailing,top,bottom) == Cell(leading,trailing,top,bottom)
4. Write dataSource and delegate methods and UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout methods.

and change Following Methods to increase button height According To Screen

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width/2, height: self.view.bounds.height*0.15)
}
```